# Export texture plane displacement for cam process

Tags: export

I have been able to apply a image (photo) as texture to a plane and displace the image creating a 3D image displacement of the plane.  Visible in render only.
I simply want to export as some type of solid that I can import into a cam software and generate a g code.
When I export it as several different formats I either get an empty plane or nothing at all.
Is there some conversion that must take place first and if so how do I do it.  Thanks for any help in advance.

Comment: As you said, the displacement you created is visible in render only - this is because there is no geometry really being displaced - to get the displacement in other software, you have to make the displacement with a _Displacement_ modifier (which requires the mesh to have a high resolution and then apply the modifier so that the displacement is truly executed on the vertices and is no longer only existent through the modifier.

Comment: Your correct.  To my amazement, After all the work in shader, maping, unwrapping and using nodes, I went into the 3D object mode and the tools on the right and added subdivision and displacement and there it was.  Right in the material view, my 3D displacement.  I  guess what I don't understand is the difference between adding displacement in the shader side as apposed to adding it in the 3D materials side.  I am guessing there is a separation in the functions.  Any explanation would help.  Thanks a lot for your help

Comment: Shader opposed to materials? You create materials in the shader editor... Anyway, with the _Feature Set_ > _Experimental_ for _Cycles_ and _Adaptive Subdivision_, you can get a highly detailed displacement with just four vertices. The _Displacement_ modifier always needs high polycounts to show displacement. Apart from that, no matter if using the shader or modifier method, they are all procedural and you can change them. As soon as you apply the modifier, the mesh cannot be altered easily anymore. But in other software the modifiers don't work, so for export you need to "destroy" the mesh.